# How to use 2 stopwords files for 2 languages

Tags: php, sphinx

I am trying to using Sphinx Stop words functionality for 2 languages having one index.

I am trying 2 add stopwords files like this

```
stopwords = /var/data/stopwords-en.txt /var/data/stopwords-ru.txt
```

By using Above pattern the stopwords for english works well but for non english language it blocks the overall search results and show 0 results.

And

```
stopwords = /var/data/stopwords-en.txt
stopwords = /var/data/stopwords-ru.txt
```

By using this the stopword functionality is not working

Looking forward for a solution for stopwords for both languages

Thanks

Comment: Why not just put all the words in one file?

Comment: Hi. 'stopwords = /var/data/stopwords-en.txt /var/data/stopwords-ru.txt' works fine for me. Can you provide more details so I can reproduce "for non english language it blocks the overall search results and show 0 results" ?

Comment: @barryhunter: One language is english and one language is Arabic thats why I made two files. Secondly I have also tried by making one file which contains both english and Arabic stopwords but still for english everything works fine but for arabic due to stopwords the search results are not returned or stopwords not works.  Any solution?

Comment: @ManticoreSearch: Can you try with english and Arabic stopwords. For english stop word functionality works fine but in Arabic stopwords functionality not works.

Comment: After changing my charset_table for arabic and adding ignore_chars, the stopwords for Arabic functionality is working fine but now for english stopwords functionality is not working.

Comment: One more thing, I have a multi lingual website. Can I control the stopwords with php code. Means I want to add a check to do not include stopwords file if website language is english

Comment: Sounds like stopwords is a Red Herring, and nothing to do with problem. Its the charset_table. It needs to be configured with all the languages characters, so English AND Arabic combined. Or may be easier to have two separate indexes (can still search both at once!)

Comment: @barryhunter: You are right. I have updated my character set by this. See my  new comments. But how can i combine characters of both english and Arabic.

Comment: @barryhunter: i got the issue: See this line:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the issue: See this line:
`$q = '"' . $cl->EscapeString($_REQUEST['input']) . '"/1 @language en';`
The @language parameter fetches extra results.  If it removed this then stop words works perfectly. But I must need this parameter to filter results according to language.

Comment: Do you perhaps have `en` as a stopword!??!!! if listed in the stopword file wont be able to match anything!